# How to import submodule from private package?

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I'm developing a private npm package written in TypeScript that has to be reused in other TS projects. I created (and published) a `@myorg/core` package, that I want to use to provide enums and types that are used amongst several repos (instead of re-declearing them each time).

In the `tsconfig.json` of the package, I have `"declaration": true` in order to export the files to describe its APIs. Indeed, when I build the .d.ts files are created.

As for the project structure

```
 src/
 ├── enumerators/
 │   └── index.ts
 ├── database-models/
 │   └── index.ts
 ├── external-apis/
 │   └── index.ts
 └── index.ts
```

The `src/index.ts` is meant to export all resources, code:

```
export * as ExternalAPIs from './external-apis';
export * as Enumerators from './enumerators';
export * as DatabaseModel from './database-model';
```

Now I would like to understand how to import any of these resources directly. What I mean is instead of doing

```
import * as MyOrgCore from '@myorg/core'
```

I would like to do

```
import * as Enumerators from '@myorg/core/Enumerators'
```

Searched for info on the internet and found suggestions about using the exports field in the package.json, here's what it looks like (simplified)

```json
{
  "name": "@myorg/core",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./Enumerators": "./dist/enumerators/index.js",
    "./ExternalAPIs": "./dist/external-apis/index.js",
    "./DatabaseModels": "./dist/database-model/index.js"
  }
}
```

This did not help, as when I import as I would like I'm getting

> Cannot find module '@myorg/core/Enumerators' or its corresponding type
> declarations.ts(2307)

So final question: what's the right way to do this? Is it even good practice?

Comment: "What's the right way to do this?" the way you're doing it. "Is it even good practice?" usually yes, depends on why you're doing it. RE the error 1. are you sure the JS and .d.ts files exist at those paths (you only posted /src, but the exports map in your package.json points to /dist)? and 2. are you seeing this error when building your project or just in your IDE?

Comment: @JaredSmith Someone on another platform suggested using `"moduleResolution": "Node16"` in the tsconfig of the projects using the core module and it solved the issue.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question for the benefit of future searchers then :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this has to do with the `tsconfig.json` of the projects that use the `core` package. All I had to do was add `"moduleResolution": "Node16"` to the config file.